# Homological Algebra Problem

Tags: homological-algebra

suppose $A^{'}$ is sub module of $A$ and $$0\rightarrow A^{'}\overset{(d^{-1})^{'}}{\rightarrow}(I^{0})^{'} \overset{(d^{0})^{'}}{\rightarrow} (I^{1})^{'}\rightarrow \ldots $$

is injective resolution for $A^{'}$ .

1) show that we can make injective resolution $0\rightarrow A \overset{d^{-1}}{\rightarrow}I^{0} \overset{d^{0}}{\rightarrow}I^{1} \rightarrow ...    $ for $A$ such that

i)$(I^{n})^{'} \subseteq I^{n} (n\geq0) $

ii)$coker((d^{n-1})^{'}) \subseteq coker (d^{n-1}) (n \geq 0)$

2) show that $$0 \rightarrow \frac{A}{A^{'}} \rightarrow \frac{I^{0}}{(I^{0})^{'}} \rightarrow \frac{I^{1}}{(I^{1})^{'}}\rightarrow \ldots $$

is injective resolution for $\frac{A}{A^{'}}$ .

this will be great if give me hint or Idea ,thanks a lot.

Comment: Can someone teach me how to prove this? Thanks.

Comment: Can someone teach me how to prove this? Thanks